# Share data between directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, mean-stack

I'm rendering a large form that is described in a json file, in my view I'm using ng-repeat and then sending each element to a 'master' directive called `FormRender`, I have a controller in this directive that is switching on `obj.QuestionType`. I then want to be able to send that object to a different directive based on its type, for example if it is a multiple choice question I want to be able to send it to `multipleRender` and then have that load the correct partial view with the data inside.

So far I'm not entirely sure how to do this, questions are described in the following format.

```
{
  "QuestionID": 1,
  "QuestionPage": 1,
  "QuestionName": "CurrentFirms",
  "QuestionType": "text",
  "QuestionLabel": "Current Firm(s)",
},
```

I'm rendering it like so

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
      <fieldset ng-repeat='item in data[0]'>
        <form-render obj='item'></form-render>
```

The `formRender` directive looks like this

```
.directive('formRender', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { obj: '=' },
    controller: function($scope) {
      var type = $scope.obj.QuestionType;
      switch(type) {
        case 'multiple':
            // send this to a different directive to handle and render
          break;
      }
    }
  };
```

What's the best way to move forward?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ngSwitch - [AngularJS ngSwitch documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) - and select the directive in the template.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <fieldset ng-repeat='item in data[0]' ng-switch on="item.QuestionType">
      <my-form-text-directive ng-switch-when="text" obj="item"></my-form-text-directive>
      <my-form-multiple-directive ng-switch-when="multiple" obj="item"></my-form-multiple-directive>
   <fieldset>
</form>
```